# P is stronger than not not P

Tags: logic

I'm trying to understand the following frame.

"The interpretation of negation is different in intuitionist logic than in classical logic. In classical logic, the negation of a statement asserts that the statement is false; to an intuitionist, it means the statement is refutable (e.g., that there is a counterexample). There is thus an asymmetry between a positive and negative statement in intuitionism. If a statement P is provable, then it is certainly impossible to prove that there is no proof of P. But even if it can be shown that no disproof of P is possible, we cannot conclude from this absence that there is a proof of P. Thus P is a stronger statement than not-not-P."

Can one give me an example on this?

Proving that 2^0.5 is not a rational number is often proved by assuming that it is rational. So it's not valid since we 'prove' a counterexample ?

Comment: Could you cite your source?

Comment: You should mention that the source of the quote is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism . Not because there is any issue with Wikipedia, but because you should always specify the source for a direct quote.

Comment: Also, the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, by showing that it is not rational, is in fact a constructive proof! To prove $\lnot P$ constructively is the same as assuming $P$ and proving a contradiction. There is a good blog post about this at http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/ and some answers on this site as well.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is actually spot on. Intuitionists reject the law of the excluded middle, and thus believe that it does not automatically follow that: $\neg \neg P \Rightarrow P$. Since the technique of proof by contradiction is to negate the negative of a statement, it is not considered by them to be a permitted technique.

Here's another example: is an irrational to an irrational necessarily an irrational? A common proof that this is false is this: let $a = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt2}$. Now, either $a$ is rational, in which case we have refuted the statement, or $a^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational, and since $a$ is irrational by assumption, we have also refuted the statement. Yet we did not construct a specific counterexample -- we don't know which case actually serves as our disproof. Most mathematicians are fine with this sort of argument, but some are not.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that intuitionists cannot assert that $\lnot \lnot P \Rightarrow P$. They cannot *disprove* that, either, so they would not want to assert $\lnot\lnot P \not\Rightarrow P$.

Comment: To emphasise Carl's point, note that in Heyting arithmetic (the intuitionistic formalisation of Peano arithmetic), one can prove (by induction) that $P \lor \lnot P$ holds for each atomic predicate $P$.

Comment: Indeed, to be clear, when I wrote that, my intention in putting the strike through the implication symbol was to indicate "it does not follow that" (as opposed to it is not so) -- I will edit the post to clarify that.

Comment: Why is $a^a$ rational if a is irrational?

Comment: Oops, my bad. It should say $a^{\sqrt2}$. Which equals $2$.